# Tor console output issue: running tor --hash-password gives no result

Tags: windows, console, tor

I'm following the blog post [here](http://sacharya.com/crawling-anonymously-with-tor-in-python/).

I'm using a Windows machine, so I can't follow the exact steps. This is what I've done:

1. Installed the [Tor Browser for Windows](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en)
2. Installed pytorctl

   ```
   pip install git+https://github.com/aaronsw/pytorctl
   ```
3. Installed [Privoxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ijbswa/files/Win32/3.0.23%20%28stable%29/privoxy_setup_3_0_23.exe/download)
4. Attempted to use the Tor command line. I'm assuming it is the exe file in the directory "Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor"

   ```
   tor --hash-password *mypassword*
   ```

**Unfortunately, this command runs but there is no response.**

If anyone has any suggestions, much would be appreciated. Do you think this could be a firewall issue?

Comment: Is it expected to have a response?

Comment: I also don't get a reponse when I do tor -h

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming it should output a hashed version of my password.

Comment: strange, it works for me on Linux & on OSX

Comment: @JPN see my answer below, did that help at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug that when your run tor.exe from the command line it is running but opens in a hidden window. To get around this, run the following: `tor --hash-password *your_password* | more`. Hopefully this works. See more about the issue [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/is-the-latest-tor-0-2-5-10-expert-bundle-broken/6199#6199).